# VLC Stuttering when playing videos

Tags: windows-8.1, video, vlc-media-player

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I'm trying to play a 1080p video using VLC, but it keeps stuttering. I tried different solutions like going to tools > preferences > video > video codecs > FFmpeg and changing "skip the loop" to "Disable", and few other steps, but it's not working. Any help is absolutely appreciated.

Comment: you can either use [DivX Plus](http://www.divx.com/en/divx-plus-player) or [5K Player](http://www.5kplayer.com/5kplayer-download-windows.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It may be the PC simply cannot keep up with the processing needed.

However, you might try free [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/), which seems to demand fewer resources (though it is not as flexible as VLC). On my PC's, I install both.

Comment: I was basically using MPC, but there were video and audio lags; so I had to install VLC, which operated better than MPC despite the stutter thing.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. You might get a better answer if you provide some details on the PC, such as CPU and RAM, and on the CPU load (shown in Task Manager). Perhaps other processes are stealing time.

Comment: Well, the processor is AMD with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics, 6GB Ram, 64-bit OS. Any more details wanted?

Comment: I guess the problem isn't with all videos. I played another 1080p video, it worked smoothly, yet the problem remains with the other one.

Comment: Your system seems powerful enough not to be the cause of the issue. As you state, it might be the file. BTW, some video formats, such as MPEG (MP4) are quite tolerant of damaged files, and will play them with just short "drop-outs", which may be the problem you're having.

Comment: The video I said is working smoothly is MP4, the other one is mkv. :D
Anyway, thanks a million for your help, I appreciate it.